# dynamically created iframe triggers onload event twice

Tags: javascript, iframe

I created an iframe dynamically and found that this iframe trigger onload event twice.

```
var i=0;
frameOnload=function(){
  console.log(i++);  
};

var ifr=document.createElement("iframe");  
ifr.src="javascript:(function(){document.open();document.write('test');document.close();})();";
ifr.onload=frameOnload;  
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
```

Why i finally is 1?
How to prevent iframe's onload twice instead of pointing onload function to null inside itself?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle so you can test it easily: https://jsfiddle.net/o34s8kk5/2/ and indeed the double call happens on webkit only

Comment: I am facing similar situation in IOS and android. can anybody help ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I've also encountered the same problem, but get no answer anywhere, so I tested by myself.

The iframe onload event will be triggered twice in webkit browsers ( safari/chrome ), if you attach the onload event BEFORE the iframe is appended to the body.

So you can prevent iframe onload twice by change your code in the following way.

```
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
ifr.onload=frameOnload; // attach onload event after the iframe is added to the body
```

Then, you will only get one onload event, which is the event the document really loaded.

Comment: Same here. I had double onload event calls in the case I had an onload="function1()" and after appending it in the page, I was doing a one('load', function2) with jquery, resulting in a double call of the function1 on the latest version of chrome... weird stuff.

Comment: Oh my god, I've been dealing with this issue for about six months. Why isn't this an accepted answer? The SO gods should automatically accept answers with high upvote counts on questions at least a year old.

Answer (score 30):

To expand on the top-voted answer: *if you can not control when and how things are attached to the DOM -- for instance, when using a framework* (we've had this happening in our Angular app) -- *you might want to try the solution below.*

I did heavy cross-browser testing and I found the following workaround: **check the parameter passed to `onload` callback and inspect `evt.target.src` in the event listener.**

```
iframe.onload = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.src != '') {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

(if you call global method from HTML, remember to pass `event` in your HTML markup: `<iframe onload="window.globalOnLoad(event)">`)

`evt.target.src` can be be `''` (empty string) only in webkit in the first `onload` call, from my tests.

## *Study of iframe onload behavior in different situations*

```
iframe.onload = function(evt){
    console.log("frameOnload", ++i);
    console.log("src = '" + evt.target.src + "'");
};
```

### iframe onload behavior with regular URL

```
// Chrome:  onload 1 src='', onload 2 src=requestedSrc
// IE11:    onload 1 src=requestedSrc
// Firefox: onload 1 src=requestedSrc
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "http://www.example.org/";
```

### iframe onload behavior with 404 URL

```
// Chrome:  onload 1 src='', onload 2 src=requestedSrc
// IE11:    onload 1 src=requestedSrc
// Firefox: onload 1 src=requestedSrc
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "http://www.example.org/404";
```

### iframe onload behavior with non-resolvable (at DNS level) URL

```
// Chrome:  onload 1 src='', onload 2 src=requestedSrc
// IE11:    onload 1 src=requestedSrc
// Firefox: onload NEVER triggered!
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src= 'http://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.example/';
```

### iframe onload behavior with `iframe.src` explicitly set to `about:blank` before appending to DOM

```
// Chrome:  onload 1 src='about:blank', onload 2 src=requestedSrc
// IE11:    onload 1 src=requestedSrc
// Firefox: onload 1 src=requestedSrc
iframe.src = "about:blank";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "http://www.example.org/";
```

### iframe onload behavior with `iframe.src` explicitly set to a javascript expression before appending to DOM

```
// Chrome:  onload 1 src='javascript:void 0', onload 2 src=requestedSrc
// IE11:    onload 1 src=requestedSrc
// Firefox: onload 1 src=requestedSrc
iframe.src = "javascript:void 0";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "http://www.example.org/";
```

Comment: I am using DevExpress MVC and I see `event.target.src` is not empty string on the first `load`, but is some DevExpress internal url.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this happen to asynchronously loaded stylesheets, like this one.

```
<link rel="preload" href="stylesheet.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

I find that the simplest solution is to have the event remove itself:

```
<link rel="preload" href="stylesheet.css" as="style" onload="this.removeAttribute('onload'); this.rel='stylesheet'">
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, while I was able to reproduce double `onload` in case where `iframe.src` is `javascript:`, I was not able to reproduce it with a normal HTTP URL (onload was happening once). However, when you change the order of calls so that `iframe.src` is set after appending to body, then the double-load happens (again, webkit only):

```
var i = 0;

var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.onload = function(){
  console.log("frameOnload", ++i);
};
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "http://www.example.org/";
//iframe.src = "http://www.example.org/404";

// double onload!
```

When I **assign `src` before appending**, I get one `onload` call.

```
var i = 0;

var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.onload = function(){
  console.log("frameOnload", ++i);
};
iframe.src = "http://www.example.org/";
//iframe.src = "http://www.example.org/404";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

// only one onload
```

Answer (score 0):

Here code that works good!

Credit: @Dave Stolie https://coderanch.com/t/443223/languages/Frames-loading-refresh

```
<html>  
 <head>  
   <script type="text/javascript">  
     function loadFrame()  
     {
        var url="http://www.google.com";
        alert(document.getElementById("theFrame").src);

        if (document.getElementById("theFrame").src != url)
        {
            alert("loading");
            document.getElementById("theFrame").src = url;  
        }
     }  
   </script>  
   </head>  
   <body onLoad="loadFrame();">  
   <iframe id="theFrame" src="x"/>
  </body>  
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jakub.g's answer:

From inside the frame, the `evt.target.src` hack does not work. But I found that I could instead check the `evt.target.title`. The second time `DOMContentLoaded` is triggered, `evt.target` points to the document being loaded, so this would work:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.title !== myPageTitle) {
    // Work around for Webkit browsers trigging this event twice om iframes
    return
  }
  // DOM content loaded, for real
}
```

This behavior seems to be consistent even in Internet Explorer (save for old versions without `.addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in vue.js 2.6.12 
I handled it by checking if event.target.url matches the src url inside the onload function of iframe.

```
<template>
           <iframe
                @load="onLoad"
                :src="embedUrl"
                ref="cardNumber"
                frameborder="0"
                scrolling="no"
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                align="left"
            ></iframe>
</template>


<script>
export default {
...,
methods: {
onLoad (event) {
    // considerting iframe to be loaded if the event.target.url matches the src url
    if(event.target.src === this.embedUrl)) {
      // instructions after loading
    } 
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Register for onload event after appending iframe. This solves my problem.
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
ifr.onload=frameOnload;  

E.G:
iframeContainer.appendChild(iframe)
  iframe.onload = function() {
    console.log("iframe onload called")
  iframeContainer.appendChild(iframe)
  iframe.onload = function() {
    console.log("iframe onload called")
  }  
    
  }
```