# onload bug in Google Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, webkit

I have various links that open `bootstrap` `modals`. Some of the modals open with simple `html` content inside, others contain an `iframe`.

I am using `ng-switch` to determine which content type to load into the modal. This issue is only taking place in Google Chrome and Safari (i.e. webkit browsers).

I am using `onload` in the iframe to call a function once the iframe is instantiated.

```
<div class="modal-body" ng-switch="modal.type">
   <div ng-switch-when="iframe">
      <iframe ng-src="http://plunker.co/group" onload="callMeMaybe();"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div ng-switch-when="html">
      <h1>I'm just plain ol' html up in here.</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The issue:** Chrome and Safari call the onload function twice. Whereas Firefox and IE properly call the function once.

What can I do to prevent this behavior in Chrome/Safari?

Here's a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/X1q4dcjv0ur7lm7fnoCY?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, on webkit browsers, the onload event on a iframe triggers twice. Once when the iframe is created and then, when the src is set.

According to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880489/3170216

You can prevent this behavior if you attach the onload event **after** your iframe element is appended to the body. But i'm not sure how to do that in your situation.