# Waiting for multiple iFrames to load before executing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

Forgive my naivety, this probably is quite obvious, I just can't see it now.

Please tell me what is wrong with the following code:

```
    $('#iframe1').load(function(){
      $('#iframe2').load(function(){
        alert('loaded!');
      });
    });
```

The idea is to wait until both iframes have fully loaded, then alert "loaded" - of course this is a simplified example for the sake of stack.

The script sits in script tags at the end of the body of the html doc.

Comment: Everytime the content of `#iframe1` changes, you *add* a `load` event handler to `#iframe2`.

Comment: Ok, I guess that was wrong :-) Can you explain this in an answer, and maybe explain a bit more what the solution could be?

Comment: The answer provided by @slash197 is the closest to what I would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you expect 2nd iframe to load after the first one?

```
~function () {
  var loaded = 0;

  $('#iframe1, #iframe2').load(function (){
    if (++loaded === 2) {
      alert('loaded!');
    }
  });
}()
```

Comment: If you're wondering why there's a tilde (~) before the function, read this: https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2016/07/31/js-tilde-iief/

Comment: @jbyrd It doesn't need to be a tilde. I've noticed that `+`, `-` and `!` work too.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - yes those work, too, but are slightly different - you can read the link above to see why tilde is probably the best.

Comment: @jbyrd, `!` is the same - no binary form.

Comment: @jbyrd It is as good or as bad as any other. Javascript used newlines **and** semicolons to delimit statements. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel, the point is that with unary operator `!` or `~` if there is a newline, your code doesn't depend on the previous nor doesn't spoil previous. In case of `+` or `-` if there is no semicolon, such operator will be treated as binary and will spoil the prevoius code reagardless newline. And the same problem with braces.

Answer (score 4):

@Quertiy answer is perfectly fine, but not very jQuery-ish. It is hard-coded for 2 iframes only.

The beauty of jQuery is that you can make it work for the most number of people, with as little friction as possible.

I've advised a **very** simplistic plugin that does nearly what is present on that answer, but in a more open way. It not only works on iframes, but also on images, audio, video and whatever has a `onload` event!

Without further due, here's the code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({allLoaded: function(fn){
        if(!(fn instanceof Function))
        {
            throw new TypeError('fn must be a function');
        }

        var $elems = this;
        var waiting = this.length;

        var handler = function(){
            --waiting;
            if(!waiting)
            {
                setTimeout(fn.bind(window), 4);
            }
        };

        return $elems.one('load.allLoaded', handler);
    }});
})(window.jQuery);
```

It works by adding a `load` handler to every element in that selection. Since it is a plugin, you can use in whatever way you decide to use it.

Here's an example, that loads 30 random images:

```js
//plugin code
(function($){
 $.fn.extend({allLoaded: function(fn){
  if(!(fn instanceof Function))
  {
   throw new TypeError('fn must be a function');
  }
  
  var $elems = this;
  var waiting = this.length;
  
  var handler = function(){
   --waiting;
   if(!waiting)
   {
    setTimeout(fn.bind(window), 4);
   }
  };
  
  return $elems.one('load.allLoaded', handler);
 }});
})(window.jQuery);



$(function(){

 //generates the code for the 30 images
 for(var i = 0, html = ''; i < 30; i++)
  html += '<img data-src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/?_=' + Math.random() + '">';
 
 //stuffs the code into the body
 $('#imgs').html(html);
 
 //we select all images now
 $('img')
  .allLoaded(function(){
   //runs when done
   alert('loaded all')
  })
  .each(function(){
   //the image URL is on a `data` attribute, to delay the loading
   this.src = this.getAttribute('data-src')
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="imgs"></div>
```

---

Your problem, as said before many times, is that you have a `load` event attached to your iframe. That event is fired **everytime** the content change.

After that, you set **a new event on `#iframe2`**. When it's content changes, it will fire events left and right, above and beyound what you wish!

The best aproach is to keep track of which ones you loaded or not. After all have been loaded, you simply run the function.

Comment: For some reason, this is not working on initial load. I have a page with 4 iframes, and I'm using $frames.allLoaded(), and putting an `alert()` in my callback. On initial load, it says all frames are loaded before any of them are loaded. If I then do a page refresh, it works properly. Any ideas?

Comment: @jbyrd Yes. But can I see a test page? My wild guess is that there is a brief time where the content of the iframe is being downloaded and that isn't cached. Once it is cached, it should work properly. Remember, the `load` event, on an iframe, is triggered when you change the `src` attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, my test page is an internal project. But - it's old legacy code, and I did realize that the frames' document.location is actually getting dynamically set - this may indeed be messing with the load logic. I'm guessing it's registered as loaded, but then the location gets changed and so visually different content is then getting loaded. And I'm guessing the only sure-fire way the make sure all frames are finished loading in this scenario is to put a window.onload event on the file itself (the file that's getting loaded). Would you agree?

Comment: @jbyrd Yes, I agree. And remember that you have to (somehow) pass that "flag" to the top window, where you have your nice code. I can't do that with my code, due to cross-origin restrictions, which would trigger many, many warnings and throw exceptions.

Comment: Ok great - I'm on same-origin, so it's working for me to pass a flag to the parent window. Thanks!

Comment: @jbyrd You're welcome. If you want, you can try something from here: https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're waiting until `#iframe1` loads before you attach a handler for `#iframe2` loading. So if `#iframe2` loads first, you'll never get your callback.

Instead, watch the `load` event on both of them and track which ones you've seen:

```
var seen1 = false,
    seen2 = false;
$('#iframe1, #iframe2').load(function(){
    if (this.id == "iframe1") {
        seen1 = true;
    } else {
        seen2 = true;
    }
    if (seen1 && seen2) {
        alert('loaded!');
    }
});
```

Comment: (If you see a missing `}` above, hit refresh.)

Comment: This makes sense to me now.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: Almost everything can be more compact, but when demonstrating a concept, compact is sometimes antithetical to the goal.

Comment: This is where you could explain the code: compact or not ;o)

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ: The introduction is sufficient explanation for such simple code.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ what about the other answer. Does that have a sufficient explanation? Instead seems like asking question in the answer ;P..........

Comment: @T.J.Crowder For your answer, i agree.

Comment: @Jai The other answer lacks of explanation. A mix between this answer and the other would be great, imo.

Comment: @Jai, if you are talking about my answer, yes it is an explanation. And it is [allowed](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317780/4928642) to answer in questioning form.

Comment: In my opinion, both answers were perfect for my problem, so I checked both of them, and they both worked. Both could use more explanation for the sake of people (like me) who don't have sufficient understanding of JS and jQuery to really grasp the solutions, but that's up to us to get more experience, you guys are not here to teach us. In this case I went with the more compact solution, actually because there are 5 iframes, not 2. @T.J.Crowder - Thanks you very much anyway! Very helpful! :-)

Comment: @asimovwasright: Perfectly reasonable. Beware of duplicate `load` events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781880/dynamically-crated-iframe-triggers-onload-event-twice