# Iframe load event fires twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe

The function bound to (`@load="myFunction"`) fires once when the iframe is created and once when it's actually loaded.

Why does it fire when the iframe is created, and how to avoid it?

```
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div v-if="webviewOpen">
      <transition name="content" appear>
        <div v-if="webviewOpen">
            <transition name="iframe">
            <iframe
              v-show="showIframe"
              :src="webviewUrl"
              @load="iframeIsLoaded"
            />
          </transition>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      showIframe: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      webviewOpen: state => state.webview.open,
      webviewUrl: state => state.webview.url
    })
  },
  watch: {
    webviewOpen () {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showIframe = true
      }, 1000)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    iframeIsLoaded () {
      console.log('iframe loaded')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: We need more code. The problem is elsewhere. This code loads only once for me.

Comment: Still only `console.log`s once for me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880489/871404 clearly this problem is faced by many people. I tried this answer and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @drake035, It is clearly [not happening](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/gw514qdx/) in latest Chrome, using Vue `2.6.12`. Provide a [mcve] specifying at least one browser in which it happens. Without a way to reproduce, nobody can provide a fix. Most likely something else (layout structural directives e.g `v-if`, `v-for`) is causing your `<iframe>` to be removed from DOM and then added again. What you have posted so far cannot be tested.

Comment: A wild guess here is your component starts with a truthy value for `webviewOpen`, which is swiftly (possibly in `mounted()`) changed to a falsy value. This could cause the `<iframe>` to fire `@load` before the execution of `mounted()`, if the `src` is falsy at that point - as it doesn't take any time to load. Obviously, the `@load` will fire again when you switch `webviewOpen` to a truthy value later on. This is pure speculation, since you haven't provided a way to repro, hence test. But if the assumption is true, initializing `webviewOpen` as falsy would fix it.

Comment: You were right, something else was interfering. I created an answer to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tao suggested something else was interefering, namely [Nuxt Lazy Load](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-lazy-load) package. So if anyone uses this package AND finds out iframes onload event mysteriously fires twice AND finds this thread:

Add `iframes: false` in your `nuxt.config.js` when importing the package inside the `modules` section. Problem solved!

Answer (score 3):

It seems it may be a web kit issue with firing twice ( safari/chrome ) as it fires when added to DOM (v-if on parent) and when the content is loaded. It may help to add .once modifier to the @load.once="myFunction()"

Comment: Thanks, it now fires once but at iframe creation not when the iframe is loaded (which is what we want)

Answer (score 1):

We know from your [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880489/10549827) that Chrome shows this issue unless you attach the listener *after* the `iframe` is appended to the DOM. To do this, we could take advantage of Vue's [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram). We want it to happen after the `iframe` is added to the DOM, but before it has a chance to load, so we'll use the `updated` hook.

I don't experience the problem in any of my browsers, so I unfortunately can't really test it for you. Test for yourself and see if something like this fixes it for you:

```
<template>
  <label for="show">Show iFrame</label>
  <input id="show" type="checkbox" v-model="webviewOpen">
  <div v-if="webviewOpen">
    <iframe
      src="https://testwebsite.com/"
      @load="iframeLoadHelper"
      frameborder="0"
    ></iframe>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      webviewOpen: false,
      iframeReady: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // Helper method, just to keep 'if' outside of the logic of your potentially
    // complex @load method
    iframeLoadHelper() {
      if (this.iframeReady) return this.iframeLoaded();
      else return; // do nothing
    },
    // The real load method
    iframeLoaded() {
      console.log('iframe loaded');
    }
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('changing ready-state');
    this.iframeReady = this.webviewOpen;
  }
};
</script>

<style>
:root { font-family: sans-serif; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am already using a `count` variable to only trigger my `iframeLoaded` code when the iframe is actually loaded (second call). But I'm looking for a more elegant, idiomatic solution without such hacky workaround :)

Comment: @drake035 My example is only using the `count` data member to be able to display the count in the DOM. The way it actually functions is by using Vue's `updated` lifecycle hook to set a flag once the `iframe` is added to the DOM. Then the function call is skipped if that flag is not set. This means that the function will only be called after the `iframe` is added to the DOM, which is what generally triggers the first listener. Then, when hiding the frame, the same lifecycle hook sets the flag to false again. Basically, would work the same without `count`; that's only for display purposes.

Comment: @drake035 I've cleaned up my answer and removed the `count` variable to make it a little clearer.